# Ubuntu 18.04 Stuck on boot logo. stops after line: [OK] Started User Manager for UID 1000

Tags: boot

I just started learning how to use different commands on the terminal but somehow managed to mess something up. I tried installing fcitx-mozc for japanese input, but after trying to restart my laptop, it would no longer get passed the ubuntu loading logo. My mouse cursor still appears and moves. I tried going into the root, recovery mode and uninstalled fcitx-mozc from the command line but that didn't seem to work. I've also tried booting ubuntu where it shows all the commands but stops on the following line : [OK] Started User Manager for UID 1000
I have no idea what to do as I am new to this but managed to mess something up. I'm running ubuntu 18.04 on a Thinkpad 13 laptop
thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm having the same problem after machine shut down because of an empty battery.